# PHP PDO Statement inserting Null value to Db table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PHP PDO Statement inserting Null value to Db table

**MY CODE:-**

```
function pdate_product_desc_preview($fieldvalues, $company_digms1, $company_digms2, $company_digms3)
 {
    $query = "INSERT INTO eco_product_descTemp(`blockdigms1`, `blockdigms2`, `blockdigms3`) values(:company_digms1,:company_digms2,:company_digms3)";
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(":company_digms1", $company_digms1);
        echo $company_digms2;
        $stmt->bindValue(":company_digms2", $company_digms2);
        echo $company_digms3;
        $stmt->bindValue(":company_digms3", $company_digms3);
        $stmt->execute();
        var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
        $productid = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        return $productid;


    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

When i am executing, it only insert null value with auto increment id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably means that either your data is null, or that the datatype you give to your database is incorrect and gets set to null. Try doing `var_dump($company_digms1, $company_digms2, $company_digms3, $fieldValues);` at the start of your function and check if that data is what you're expecting

Comment: when i am echoing it showing real values

Comment: var_dump also displaying value.when i am inserting into table, its null

Comment: What variable is it adding NULL to?

Comment: And what is fieldvalues? as you're not even calling it

Answer (score 0):

```
function pdate_product_desc_preview($fieldvalues, $company_digms1, $company_digms2, $company_digms3)
 {
    $query = "INSERT INTO eco_product_descTemp (`blockdigms1`, `blockdigms2`, `blockdigms3`) values(:company_digms1,:company_digms2,:company_digms3)";
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(":company_digms1", $company_digms1);
        echo $company_digms2;
        $stmt->bindParam(":company_digms2", $company_digms2);
        echo $company_digms3;
        $stmt->bindParam(":company_digms3", $company_digms3);
        $stmt->execute();
        var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
        $productid = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        return $productid;


    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

Try this one.
Just replacing **bindValue** with **bindParam**

You can check [prepared-statements.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) here.

Comment: Hello @Abdul if my answer is work for you then just accept my answer and close your question.Thank you

Comment: Still,Its inserting null value only

Comment: `bind_param ` is not a PDO function

Answer (score 0):

I've left `$fieldvalues` in but i dont see what it is doing..

Here's my take on it:

```
function pdate_product_desc_preview($fieldvalues, $company_digms1, $company_digms2, $company_digms3)
{
    if (!empty($company_digms1) && !empty($company_digms2) && !empty($company_digms3))
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `eco_product_descTemp` (`blockdigims1`, `blockdigims2`, `blockdigims3`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->execute([$company_digms1, $company_digms2, $company_digms3]);

        echo 'Inserted!';
    } else {
        echo 'make sure all fields have been filled in!';
    }
}
```

So on the condition that if none of the fields are empty (NULL) then run the query. If one is empty (NULL) then run the `make sure` statement.

Comment: *when i am echoing it showing real values var_dump also displaying value.when i am inserting into table, its null*  This means it might happen that his db dataTypes are wrong

Comment: Very true there @Masivuye